# List search return error if the item from a list is null - blocked from the search

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a search for the list display. There are fields in the list which are `null` and when i try to search it return error(which is obvious). i tried to handle it in filter method but it does not work.

Here is a sample code where if any one of the query is null it does not work.

```
var appData = query.isEmpty
              ? data
              : data
                  .where((element) =>
                      element.gateApptNum
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                      element.truckPlateNbr
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                      element.gateAppointment[0].containerNum != null
                          ? element.gateAppointment[0].containerNum
                          : 'false'
                              .toLowerCase()
                              .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                      element.truckPlateNbr
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                  .toList();
```

Below is the error i get if i tried to handle the error in filter

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `null` checks for each field, then default to `false` for a null value like so:

```
var appData = query.isEmpty
    ? data
    : data.where((element) =>
        (element.gateApptNum
            ?.toLowerCase()
            ?.contains(query.toLowerCase()) ?? false) ||
        (element.truckPlateNbr
            ?.toLowerCase()
            ?.contains(query.toLowerCase()) ?? false) ||
        (element.gateAppointment[0]?.containerNum
            ?.toLowerCase()
            ?.contains(query.toLowerCase()) ?? false) ||
        (element.truckPlateNbr
            ?.toLowerCase()
            ?.contains(query.toLowerCase()) ?? false)
      ).toList();
```

Comment: I tried and look like if one is null it does not work others all well, could you please post some sample example @lee3

Comment: Please check my updated answer for a full solution using the code you shared.

Answer (score 1):

In the code snippet in the description you are using [where method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) to filter `null` values, the method takes a predicate which returns `bool` value but in the snippet in the ternary expression if the condition is `true` then you are returning `element.gateAppointment[0].containerNum` which may be a `String` and not `bool`.

I think evaluating just condition to filter out `null` values would be better like below.

```
.where((element) =>
                  element.gateApptNum
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                  element.truckPlateNbr
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                  element.gateAppointment[0].containerNum != null)
```

if you want to change the elements then you can use [map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) after `where`.

If you wan to return `element.gateAppointment[0].containerNum` then you can return it like this:

```
var appData = query.isEmpty
          ? data
          : data
              .where((element) =>
                  element.gateApptNum
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                  element.truckPlateNbr
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                  element.gateAppointment[0].containerNum != null
              )
              .map((element) => element.gateAppointment[0].containerNum)
              .toList();
```

Comment: Looks good but could you please add some example or something @yashwant

Comment: please refer to my updated answer @SatishRaizada .